# Animate CC - getChildByName canvas vs WebGL

Tags: javascript, flash, adobe, createjs

Afternoon. I have an FLA with a single `MovieClip` on the stage - the clip is named myThing in the Library and also has an instance name of myThing. On another layer I have the following script:

```
this.myThing=this.getChildByName("myThing");
console.log(this.myThing);
```

When I run this in a `WebGL` project it works as I'd expect and returns a JS object but when I run the same thing in a `canvas` project (which is what I need to use) it comes back `null`.

Initially, can anyone explain what the difference is between a WebGL and a canvas project in Adobe Animate CC and how I can get a reference to child clips to control their timelines?

Along with that, can anyone point me to any decent resources on scripting these projects? It seems like no matter what I search for I always end up back at that *!@%£¡ rabbit tutorial that manages to cram very little info into an awful lot of words.

Thanks all, your help is always appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

So I was being a numpty.

The `name` property of any asset defaults to `null`. This is not a problem because the `getChildByName()` method is not really necessary (for me at least) once I realise that you can just call `this.someChild.someMethod()`.

I got hooked up on the wrong approach because it was the only one I could find examples of. I'm still finding documentation very sketchy and not very helpful when compared to AS3 or even competing JS libraries like [Greensock](http://greensock.com/gsap)

Also not sure why my first approach worked in WebGL but not canvas. Ah well, onwards and upwards...

Comment: Pretty sure Animate does not set the name property to the instance name when exporting to CreateJS. A number of people have requested it, so perhaps log a bug on http://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/issues/ ... Glad you found a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

WebGL and HTML5 Canvas documents work somewhat differently in Animate CC. 
In WebGL, symbols having instance names are accessible as follows:

```
var mySymbol = this.getChildByName("instance-name");
```

In Canvas, the same can be done as follows:

```
var mySymbol = this.instance-name;
```

Unnamed instances can be referenced using `this.getChildAt(index)` in both canvas and WebGL.
Once a reference to the required instance is obtained, you can easily control it as desired. (gotoAndPlay()/Stop() etc.)

PS: In canvas, Symbol-instance names are not explicitly set as name properties of corresponding symbols in the output - hence the name property is returned as null.